# descriptive statistics

Tags: probability

A clothing store wants to fire some employees. They decide to fire the employees who are selling at the bottom 15% of all sales people for the store. The mean total is 430 a day sold with a standard deviation of 50. What is the least amount that a salesperson can sell and remain employed?

Comment: How are the sellings distributed ? Normally ?

Comment: Is the question too difficult ?

Comment: Please see my answer below; if you have additional questions on this topic, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the bottom 15%. *Assuming* this follows a normal model you can use:  InverseNorm(.15,430,50)..I think it's called invNorm in a graphing calculator.. In addition, if you were curious about the top 15% you would do 1-.15 for this so it would be invNorm(.85,430,50).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this follows a Normal distribution, you should actually use `invNorm(.15, 430, 50)` since you are looking for the **bottom 15%** of all salesmen.

`invNorm(.15, 430, 50)` yields $\approx 378.178$.

Therefore, the least amount that a salesperson can sell and remain employed is $378.18.

Hope this helps!